# How to print the length of a given argument in user-defined Python functions?

Tags: python, function, arguments, python-3.x

I have defined a function in Python which requires 4 variables as parameters. I want to print the length of the given arguments, and make a loop if the number of arguments is not equal to the number of arguments required for this function.

For example:

```
def X(a,b,c,d):
  if not len([a,b,c,d]) == 4:
    print("4 arguments are required for function X")
```

I am looking for something like `len(argv())`.

Comment: Why not have the caller try and catch the error that will be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

We can print the number of arguments passed to a function using the following code:

```
def my_function(*args, **kwargs): 
  print len(args) + len(kwargs)
```

If you are asking to get the number of arguments passed to your program, you would want to use `len(sys.argv)`. Not totally clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking:

```
def func(*args):
    if not len(args) == 4:
        print("4 arguments are required for function X")
    else:
        a, b, c, d = args
```